# Replacing lines with a part of that line in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on files with transcripts. I have lines of text and every few lines there is a statement similar to this 'Play video starting at 16 seconds and follow transcript0:16' (there might be more words when minutes are showing). I was able to isolate the text I want to replace the whole sentence with. So the end goal is to leave all the text from the file but replace the sentences with my shorter text - in my case it will be "transcript0:16"

```
with open("transcript.txt", "r") as fhandle:

    newline=[]

    for line in fhandle.readlines():
        if  line.startswith("Play video"):
            words = line.split()
            word = words[::-1]
            wordfinal = word[0]
            newline.append(line.replace(line,wordfinal))

with open("transcript.txt", "w") as fhandle:

    for line in newline:
        fhandle.writelines(line)
```

Thanks

Comment: Sounds to me that you can just pop 8 words of the front of the line.

Comment: what's the problem then?

Comment: Could you tell me how to pop the words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append all the lines of your document in `newline` and apply your rule if the statement is true, otherwise just append the normal line:

```
newline=[]

for line in fhandle.readlines():
    if line.startswith("Play video"):
        words = line.split()
        word = words[::-1]
        wordfinal = word[0]
        newline.append(wordfinal))
    else:
        newline.append(line)

for line in newline:
    fhandle.writelines(line)
```